# Uninstall Adobe Illustrator CC 2018

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, adobe-illustrator

Few months ago i had to install Adobe Illustrator CC 2018 for user,
who had Adobe account with license.
Now this user is away and i need to clean that computer.

I tried unistall from:

- "Apps & features"
- "Uninstall or change a program"
- ">Illustrator_Set-Up.exe /uninstall" from administrator command prompt

But it only opens "Creative Cloud" window where it needs log-in information. (Or "No internet connection" if no network connected)
Can i uninstall without finding someone with account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Adobe article
[Uninstall Creative Cloud apps](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/uninstall-remove-app.html)
has these instructions:

> 1. Open the Creative Cloud desktop app by clicking the *Creative Cloud icon* [image] in your taskbar
>      (Windows) or the Apple menu bar (Mac OS). If you aren’t automatically
>      signed in, sign in using your Adobe ID and password.
> 2. Click the *Apps* tab to display a list of installed apps.
> 3. In the Installed Apps section, find the app that you want to uninstall. Then, click the arrow next to *Open* or *Update*. In the
>      list that appears, click *Manage*.
> 4. Click *Uninstall*.
> 5. Follow the onscreen instructions.

If this fails for some reason, you might download from Adobe and use the
[Creative Cloud Cleaner Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html).

Comment: Ok, that's useful, other Adobe Creative instructions was claiming i can uninstall software by normal user means from Add or Remove programs, which seems not to be true.
So how do i get Adobe ID?

Comment: The id is supposed to exist already. Does the desktop app request it?

Comment: Yes, desktop app is not logged in and presented me with login screen. Options are: sign in with Email address + password; "Forgot password?"; "Get an Adobe ID"; "Sign in with an Enterprise ID"; "Or sign in with Facebook | Google"

Comment: Ideally you should login with the same id as before. If you don't know the id, or if you know it but not the password and don't have access to the email for the "Forgot password?" option, then try creating an id of your own.

Comment: I gave it my Gmail data and it let me uninstall Adobe Illustrator. Then i was able to uninstall Creative Cloud normally.